# swift CGPath is moved few pixels

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, cgpath

I have got a problem with cgpath. My cgpath are moved few pixels.How to set cgpath under the picture Can i get cgpath from png alpha ?

```
    let Mountain = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "mountain1")
    // Ground =
    Mountain.setScale(0.5)
    Mountain.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.width+(Mountain.frame.width/2)+CGFloat.random(min: 0, max: 100), y: startGround.frame.height-43 + Mountain.frame.height/2)
    let path = CGMutablePath()
    path.addLines(between: [CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.0),CGPoint(x: 246.0, y: 510.0)])
    path.addLines(between: [CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 700.0),CGPoint(x: 246.0, y: 510.0)])
    Mountain.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFrom: path)
```

[image]

Comment: Solution but i am not sure it is good idea may i can export it from png:        path.addLines(between: [CGPoint(x: -Mountain.frame.width/2, y: -Mountain.frame.height/2),CGPoint(x: 246.0-Mountain.frame.width/2, y: 510.0-Mountain.frame.height/2)])

Comment: And setScale doesnt scale our path.

Comment: Have you tried lineJoinStyle ?